# java.io.FileNotFoundException when using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I trying to read a .html resource from my current project (and parse it), as following:

[image]

The leaflet.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i'm trying to run the following code using `Jsoup`:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

// some code 

 File input = new File("\\src\\main\\resources\\leafletfile.html");
          System.out.print(input.getAbsolutePath()); // This works 
 //Exception is here:
 Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

i'm getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \src\main\resources\leafletfile.html (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Can anyone advise? thanks in advance!

Comment: could it be \\scr\\ ? :D

Comment: Apart from the obvious typo, are you sure that your runtime path is where you expect it to be? Try `input.exists()`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, its not it

Comment: "System.out.print(input.exists())"  returns false

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple file path issue the specific solution to which won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get file from resources you should use different method:

```
new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("leaflet.html").getFile());
```

Your method is looking on the file system for path you gave as parameter. Your path is not an absolute path, but relative for the jar.

If this is inside static method you should provide class name before `getClass()`, like:

```
new File(ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("leaflet.html").getFile());
```

this is because `getClass()` alone is resolved to `this.getClass()`, but there is no `this` inside static context.

Remember to clean and build after you added file to resources.

Comment: It seems like it cant find "classLoader" as a recognized class, how can i load it (its a maven project)?

Comment: I fixed the answer, check now

Comment: I'm getting the following exception : non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: You didn't mention that it is in static method. Then do this: `YourClassName.getClass()`

Comment: changed it to : File input = new File(App.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("leafletfile.html").getFile()); still not working (class name is App)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75700/discussion-between-kuba-and-yehoshaphat-schellekens).

Comment: Then again, it dosn't recognize the getClassLoader as a known method